# Spider Doesn't Follow Rules If Parse is Overridden

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using a Scrapy `CrawlSpider` to crawl a website. It grabs information from the `start_url` using the `parse` function. It also has a rule to crawl any links that contain 'pageNumber=' and grab information from those pages.

**My Problem:** The spider doesn't follow/execute the rules if I have overridden the `parse` function. If I comment out the `parse` function then the rules are followed.

I am aware that you are not supposed to call the `parse` function as a callback in a Rule and I am not but both my `parse` function and my rule callback call the same function. So this may cause an issue?

What is going wrong and how can I make the spider follow/execute the rules?

My code:

```
class BusinessFinderSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = "Business_Finder"
    allowed_domains = ["yellowpages.com.au"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.yellowpages.com.au/search/listings?clue=abc&locationClue=5000&selectedViewMode=list&eventType=sort&sortBy=distance"]
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['/search/listings.*pageNumber=']), callback="parse_sub_page")]

    # if i comment out the below function then the rules are followed
    def parse(self, response):
        return self.parse_business_list_page(response)

    def parse_sub_page(self, response):
        return self.parse_business_list_page(response)

    def parse_business_list_page(self, response):

        businesses = []
        business_divs = response.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'cell') and contains(@class, 'in-area-cell') and contains(@class, 'middle-cell')]")
        main_industry = re.search("(clue=)(.*?(?=&))", response.url).group(2)

        for business_div in business_divs:
            business = BusinessFinderItem()
            business["name"] = business_div.xpath(".//a[@class='listing-name']/text()").extract()
            ...
            businesses.append(business)

        return businesses
```

Comment: `CrawlSpider`'s `parse()` is smth that confuses people a lot, please see https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/712.

Answer (score 0):

There are mainly two types of spiders `BaseSpider` and `CrawlSpider`,

In a crawl spider if you are overriding `parse()` automatically disables the `rules` section.

Try to inherit spider from `Spider` instead of `CrawlSpider` in order to use the `parse()` but when you do, you have to extract the `urls` manually using `xpath` or something in that `parse()`. After that have to give `Request` to those `urls` with a callback function. In the callback function you will get the response and extract the contents.